# How can I add a counter for my own command that is also printed?

Tags: counters

I use the following code to draw a box with a warning sign, the word warning and the content text. The task is now to numerate the warnings. How can I print this?
For example if my warning appears in chapter 1, it shall be called warning 1.1. The next warning shall be called 1.2, etc.

```
\newcounter{myWarning}
\newcommand{\myWarning}[1]
{
  \refstepcounter{myWarning}
  \begin{longtable}[H]{|p{0.1\linewidth}m{0.9\linewidth}|}\hline
    \textbf{WARNING} & \\
    \includegraphics[width=1cm]{"CommonSubdocuments/Pictures/WarningSign"} & \textbf{#1} \\\hline
  \end{longtable}
  \addtocounter{table}{-1}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `\newcounter{myWarning}[chapter] \renewcommand*{\themyWarning}{\thechapter.\arabic{myWarning}}`?

Comment: The `longtable` approach looks weird here

Comment: For future questions: Please add a FULL MWE.

Answer (score 2):

If a counter,say foo, is defined with `\newcounter`, there's an automatic definition of `\thefoo` which defaults to `\arabic{foo}`, i.e. printing the counter values with arabic numbers.

`\newcounter{foo}[chapter]` resets the counter each time a new chapter is started (better: when `chapter` counter is increased by `\refstepcounter` or `\stepcounter`.

To change the numbering format, use `\renewcommand{\thefoo}{\thechapter.\arabic{foo}`, i.e. the foo number is preceded with the chapter number.

Here's a similar approach, where this is done automatically with a `tcolorbox` and using `number within` and `use counter=...`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{bclogo}

\newcounter{myWarning}[chapter]

%\renewcommand{\themyWarning}{\thechapter.\arabic{myWarning}}
\newtcolorbox[use counter=myWarning,number within=chapter]{warningbox}[1][]{enhanced jigsaw, sharp corners,title={Warning \thetcbcounter},#1}

\newcommand{\myWarning}[1][]{%
  \begin{warningbox}{#1}
    \textbf{WARNING}

    \bcattention% Warning sign
  \end{warningbox}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\myWarning

\myWarning

\chapter{Foobar}
\myWarning
\end{document}
```

[image]